# How do I fix my email template for just Outlook 2003, 2007 and 2013

Tags: html, css, email, templates

I've been working on an email template for my contract job and I can't for the life of me get it to work in outlook 2003, 2007 and 2013.

Here is the link to the email client test results:
http://wlsnook.createsend.com/screens/j/31DADA4FC88B5523

When you select the 3 versions of outlook indicated above, you will see that the cones are not aligned correctly. The other e-mail clients look fine.

I used a litmus built template but it does not appear to be compatible with outlook.

[Here's a link where you can view my email and the code for my email.](http://jessicadiponziano.com/code-samples/)

Can anyone help me diagnose the CSS layout issues on the page? I would appreciate it... This went from a 2 hour project to a whole day just for 3 email clients.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

You can check this website which mentions ehich css property are compatible across email client